# Symfony, reading entity fields from controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to make some kind of "reusable" base controller in Symfony 2. Given the name of an entity, is it possible to read the *schema* of that entity? That is, a list of the entity's fields with the name and the type of each one.

This is in order to automatically generate the inputs in an admin panel and other similar operations.

Comment: Take a look at the Doctrine Metadata functionality: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/metadata-drivers.html

Answer (score 1):

[**SensioGeneratorBundle**](https://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle) provides CRUD generation capabilities.

Its [source code](https://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle) is available on GitHub.
Its [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html) is well written; you should probably read it before making your decision.

This bundle can generate a CRUD controller based on a Doctrine entity. Once your application is set up, run the following command:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

It will generate forms, controllers and views.
Generated classes are easy to extend.

Comment: Thanks, it certainly looks interesting, but I'd rather have everything dinamically generated on-the-fly than creating the scaffolding statically, because any change in the model would imply regenerating everything. Currently, in a CodeIgniter implementation I've done, I have an array with the fields names and types, but that's not too elegant xD